# React Native back button not issue

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i have this code

```
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
      <Image
        source={require('./image/drawer.png')}
        style={{ width: 25, height: 25, marginLeft: 5 }}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
```

which it should go back to the previous page when I press it but i get this error
[image]

here is a link to project snack 
https://snack.expo.io/@ov3rcontrol/navi

Comment: show to us your Route file "Navigations"

Comment: https://snack.expo.io/@ov3rcontrol/navi here is full project

Comment: ok, where u put the goBake( )?

Comment: and should back me to any screen?

Comment: in the NavigationBack class in app.js
for example if you click in Category you go to other page when you click the burger menu on the top in ccategory page you should get to the home screen ( as the normal hardware back button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your snack.expo project, it appears that in each stack navigator you have `<NavigationDrawerStructure navigationProps={navigation} />` and `<NavigateBack navigationProps={navigation} />`; you're actually passing the `navigation` object to these components as a prop named `navigationProps`. So when you try to call `this.props.navigation.goBack()`, it'll rightly throw that error saying "undefined (i.e. this.props.navigation) is not an object" because it wasn't defined!

If you change `this.props.navigation.goBack()` to `this.props.navigationProps.goBack()`, you'd be calling the correct prop name. However, I'd simply recommend changing `navigationProps={navigation}` to `navigation={navigation}` so your prop names stay consistent and avoid confusion down the road while passing the navigation object.

Edit / Note: 
This will fix the error; it may not solve your desired navigation.

Comment: You are right it solved the error but it doesn't navigate back
any idea how to make it navigate 1 step back ? just like the hardware buttons do
the hardware back button works just fine 
Ty

Comment: I took another look at your snack project, and simply replacing all `navigationProps` with `navigation` seemed to work for me. Although I did notice that instead of `this.props.navigation.goBack()` I saw `this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.back())`, so perhaps that's what fixed the back button?

Comment: Ty very much indeed